# Brew Install Python Fails Due to Link gdbm link issue

Tags: python, homebrew

I am used to macport and recently got a new mac book pro 10.8.4, and I switched `brew` and tried to install python but I am getting following error:

```
brew install python --universal --framework
Error: You must `brew link gdbm' before python can be installed
```

I tried to follow following links to install python using brew but it was keep saying about link, which I don't understand.
[WebSite 1](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx.html), [webSite 2](http://bluehat.me/blog/2011/09/10/python-installation-via-homebrew/)

Here are the warnings that I get:

```
 brew install readline sqlite gdbm
Warning: readline-6.2.4 already installed
Warning: sqlite-3.7.17 already installed
Warning: gdbm-1.10 already installed, it's just not linked
```

In addition to this I have tried to link it brew link gdbm but I get the following permission issue:

```
file: /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.10/include/gdbm.h
/usr/local/include is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

I check the /usr/local/include and it has a write permission

```
drwxr-xr-x  29 root      wheel    986 Mar 30 16:46 include ( I am not the root)
```

I am not the root and don't have the root password, but I do have sudo rights on the machine.

Comment: Did you try `brew link gdbm`, as the error message recommends?

Comment: Sorry forgot to update that part in the question. yes I did and I have added extra information.

Comment: Since it's a laptop to which you don't have root access, I'm guessing you're on a single-user machine issued by your employer, in which case changing the ownership of `/usr/local/include` to your uid is probably fine. You could also change the group to one you're a member of (like `admin`, since you have `sudo` privileges), and make the directory group writeable.  The homebrew project recommends against using `sudo` to run `brew`, on security grounds, but you could also do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue., Try to change the ownership of the directory (recursively)

```
sudo chown -R username:admin /usr/local/include
```

In the above command., replace the username with your username. 
This should resolve the issue

Comment: I have the same problem too, but when I run your code I got `chown: /usr/local/include: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 5):

Running

```
brew doctor
```

and clearing warnings should fix the problem. 
It will point out a few warnings. Fixing those warnings should let brew install python with no problem afterward.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
brew unlink gdbm && brew link gdbm
```