# Brew Install Python - Unable Couldn't symlink file:

Tags: python, installation, pip, homebrew, easy-install

I having a issue in installing python using brew, Initially the problem was related to not folders not having correct permission, but thanks to a user from StackOverflow Community I managed to solve that problem. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396538/brew-install-python-fails-due-to-link-gdbm-link-issue?noredirect=1#comment25264381_17396538) for that question.

But now the problem is different I search for the same error and tried most of the solutions publish in both stackoverflow and other websites but the problem remains same.

Here is the error stack I get from brew installation:

```
Python demo
  /usr/local/share/python/Extras

Distribute and Pip have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade distribute
  pip install --upgrade pip

To symlink "Idle" and the "Python Launcher" to ~/Applications
  `brew linkapps`

You can install Python packages with (the outdated easy_install or)
  `pip install <your_favorite_package>`

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python
Warning: Could not link python. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link python'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/pip-2.7
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/local/bin/easy_install
```

I also tried solution provided by the answer in this question: [Home Brew Python Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088998/homebrew-python-installing)

Comment: From the 'Home Brew Python Installing' it looks like you need to run 'brew link --overwrite python', which will replace the existing files with the brew symlinks.  You can get more information on the files by using the --dry-run option, 'brew link --overwrite --dry-run python'.  I had a similar problem when I had the official python3 version installed which had a 2to3 symlink that blocked the brew version.